# Creating a large 2D array and populating it from a LinkedHashMap of smaller 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, path-finding

I'm trying to create a large 2D Array `int[][]` from a `LinkedHashMap` which contains a number of smaller Arrays for an A* Pathfinder I'm working on.
The `Map` the Pathfinder is using is streamed in smaller chunks to the client and converted into a simplified version for the Pathfinder.

```
Map<Coord, int[][]> pfmapcache = new LinkedHashMap<Coord, int[][]>(9, 0.75f, true);
```

The Coord look like this: `Coord(0,0)` or `Coord(-1,0)`.... etc. and the `int[][]` are always `int[100][100]` big.

Now I would like to create a new large `int[][]` that would encompass all the smaller Array where the small Array `Coord(0,0)` would be in the center of the new Large Array.

```
int[][] largearray = [-1,1][0,1][1,1]
                     [-1,0][0,0][1,0]
                     [-1,-1][0,-1][1,-1]
```

So that the large array would be `int[300][300]` big in this example. 
2. I would like to expand the new large Array if a new small array gets added to the `pfmapcache`.

```
int[][] largearray = [][][1,2]
                     [-1,1][0,1][1,1]
                     [-1,0][0,0][1,0]
                     [-1,-1][0,-1][1,-1]
```

I don't have to store the smaller Arrays in `pfmapcache` I could add them as they are created with a 2 small arrays combining etc.. but with the negative Position of the Arrays in relation to the original I have no idea how to combine them and preserve their relative postion.

First time posting here, if I need to clarify something pls let me know.

Comment: Hint: read about java coding styleguides. You use mixedCase for variable names. And you understand the cost of creating new arrays all the time, and copying around values? In other ways: have you considered to "abstract" from that "low level" two dimensional array; so that maybe your algorithm can work its data ... without having everything in one big array?

Comment: @GhostCat I believe the correct name for the Java variable naming convention is "camelcase". :)

Comment: @Jokab camelCase that would be, wouldnt it ;-)

Comment: Yes I have thought about using the "low level" 2D array in my Pathfinder but that would require me rewriting a significant portion of the Pathfinder. I will have to rewrite it eventually but I was looking for a temp solution to get It working in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You're wondering how to use your *existing* pathfinder algo with a chunked map.

This is when you need to place an [abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) between your data representation, and your data usage (like a `Landscape` class).

**Q:** Does a pathfinding algorithm need to know it works on a grid, on a chunked grid, on a sparse matrix, or on a more exotic representation?
**A:** No. A Pathfinder only needs to know one thing: 'Where can I get from here?'

---

## Ideally

you should drop any reference to the fact that your world is on a grid by working with only a class like:

```
 public interface IdealLandscape {
     Map<Point, Integer> neighbours(Point location); // returns all neighbours, and the cost to get there
 }
```

---

## Easy alternative

However I understood your existing implementation 'knows' about grids, with the added value that adjacency is implicit and you're working with points as (x, y).   You however lost this when introducing chunks, so working with the grid doesn't work anymore. So let's make the abstraction as painless as possible. Here's the plan:

### 1. Introduce a Landscape class

```
public interface Landscape {
    public int getHeight(int x, int y); // Assuming you're storing height in your int[][] map?
}
```

### 2. Refactor your Pathfinder

It's reaaally easy:
just replace `map[i][j]` with `landscape.getHeight(i, j)`

### 3. Test your refactoring

Use a very simple GridLandscape implementation like:

```
public class GridLandscape implements Landscape {
    int[][] map;
    public GridLandscape(...){
        map = // Build it somehow
    }
    @Override
    public int getHeight(int x, int y){
        return map[x][y]; // Maybe check bounds here ?
    }
}
```

### 4. Use your ChunkedGridLandscape

Now your map is abstracted away, and you know your Pathfinder works on it, you can replace it with your chunked map!

```
public class ChunkedGridLandscape implements Landscape {
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 300;
   Map<Coord, int[][]> mapCache = new LinkedHashMap<>(9, 0.75f, true);
    Coord centerChunkCoord;

    public ChunkedGridLandscape(Map<Coord, int[][]> pfmapcache, Coord centerChunkCoord){
         this.mapCache = pfmapcache;
         this.centerChunkCoord = centerChunkCoord;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight(int x, int y){
        // compute chunk coord
        int chunkX = x / CHUNK_SIZE - centerChunkCoord .getX();
        int chunkX = y / CHUNK_SIZE - centerChunkCoord .getY();
        Coord chunkCoord = new Coord(chunkX, chunkY);

        // Now retrieve the correct chunk
        int[][] chunk = mapCache.get(chunkCoord); // Careful: is the chunk already loaded?

        // Now retrieve the height within the chunk
        int xInChunk = (x + chunkX*CHUNK_SIZE) % CHUNK_SIZE; // Made positive again!
        int yInChunk = (y + chunkY*CHUNK_SIZE) % CHUNK_SIZE; // Made positive again!

        // We have everything !
        return chunk[xInChunk][yInChunk];
    }
}
```

**Gotcha:** Your `Coord` class NEEDS to have a `equals` and `hashCode` methods properly overloaded!

### 5. It just works

This should just immediately work with your pathfinder. Enjoy!